# Build project with multiple target

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I have a project, which is actually build on Win32/.Net4.0 (VS2012).
Now I need to build this project also to x64/.Net4.0, as well as Win32/3.5 and x64/3.5.

I know it's possible with 4 projects, and build every project each time.But the code is always the same, so I want to know if it possible to have one project, which is build on every target on one build process?

Thanks kooki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invoke msbuild multiple times against the same project/solution to cover all your required configurations. Just pass the configuration via the command line. So, for a Release configuration for x86:

```
msbuild MySolution.sln /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x86
```

You can then add a second call for another target platform.

Comment: I use a little different version, but your answer works too :-)